# Как при открытии и закрытии меню менять стиль для body?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть гамбургер-меню, которое открывается слева. Мне мешает скролл заднего фона. Я хочу его отключить при открытии гамбургер-меню.

Для этого я хочу, когда гамбургер-меню открыто, для body применить overflow: hidden, height: 100vh. При закрытом меню этих свойств не должно быть.

Вот мое меню:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    max-width: 1400px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/*Menu-First block*/
header {
    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: calc(1rem + 0.28vw);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
/*for desktop*/
.menu {
    padding: 3.57vw 20px;
    display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.list_menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2.8vw;
}

.list_menu li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: calc(1rem + 0.6vw);
    margin-right: 24vw;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.search_logo {
    cursor: pointer;
}
/*for mobile*/
.menu_for_mobile {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3vw 20px;
  display: none;
}

.menu_block {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
  left: -100%;
  line-height: 2.5;
  text-decoration: underline;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  background: #00897b;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.menu_block::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

.menu_block::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

.menu_block::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,199,179,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.menu_block li > a {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu_for_mobile span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 57px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  transition: .2s;
}

input:checked ~ .shadow {
  left: 0;
}

.shadow {
  transition: .001s;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  filter: blur(1px);
}

input#on {
    display: none;
}

input:checked ~ .menu_block {
  left: 0;
}

.menu_for_mobile span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

.menu_for_mobile span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
}

.menu_for_mobile span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 100%;
}

.menu_for_mobile > label {
  width: 6vw;
  min-width: 57px;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

input#on:checked ~ label > span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

input#on:checked ~ label > span:nth-child(2) {
  background: transparent;
}

input#on:checked ~ label > span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.content_block {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-indent: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
    .menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu_for_mobile {
        display: flex;
    }

    header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
            <!--For desktop-->
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="logo">Your Logo</div>
                <ul class="list_menu">
                        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Servicing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <div class="search_logo">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--For mobile-->
            <div class="menu_for_mobile">
                <input type="checkbox" id="on">
                <label for="on">
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                </label>
                <div class="shadow"></div>
                <div class="menu_block">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Servicing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    </header>

<div class="content_block">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad vel facilis dolorum, ratione blanditiis error, deserunt placeat officiis, voluptas sequi accusamus nihil quae! Debitis maiores nisi impedit velit odit nam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad vel facilis dolorum, ratione blanditiis error, deserunt placeat officiis, voluptas sequi accusamus nihil quae! Debitis maiores nisi impedit velit odit nam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad vel facilis dolorum, ratione blanditiis error, deserunt placeat officiis, voluptas sequi accusamus nihil quae! Debitis maiores nisi impedit velit odit nam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad vel facilis dolorum, ratione blanditiis error, deserunt placeat officiis, voluptas sequi accusamus nihil quae! Debitis maiores nisi impedit velit odit nam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad vel facilis dolorum, ratione blanditiis error, deserunt placeat officiis, voluptas sequi accusamus nihil quae! Debitis maiores nisi impedit velit odit nam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad vel facilis dolorum, ratione blanditiis error, deserunt placeat officiis, voluptas sequi accusamus nihil quae! Debitis maiores nisi impedit velit odit nam.</p>
</div>
```

С помощью CSS я тоже сделать этого не могу, потому что CSS - это каскадная таблица стилей и мы можем применять стили только "сверху вниз". А т.к. в body вложен input, то... Возникает вопрос: как это сделать с помощью js (не на JQuery, потому что я сейчас учу именно js)? Какие события применять (mousedown/mouseon работают не совсем так, как мне нужно)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При клике на иконку добавляем класс для `body`. При повторном клике удаляем. Пример:

```js
var menu = document.querySelector(".menu_for_mobile>input");
menu.onclick = function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("bodyhidden");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  max-width: 1400px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.bodyhidden {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/*Menu-First block*/

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: calc(1rem + 0.28vw);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}


/*for desktop*/

.menu {
  padding: 3.57vw 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.list_menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2.8vw;
}

.list_menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: calc(1rem + 0.6vw);
  margin-right: 24vw;
}

.search_logo {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*for mobile*/

.menu_for_mobile {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3vw 20px;
  display: none;
}

.menu_block {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
  left: -100%;
  line-height: 2.5;
  text-decoration: underline;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  background: #00897b;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.menu_block::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

.menu_block::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

.menu_block::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 199, 179, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.menu_block li>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu_for_mobile span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 57px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  transition: .2s;
}

input:checked~.shadow {
  left: 0;
}

.shadow {
  transition: .001s;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  filter: blur(1px);
}

input#on {
  display: none;
}

input:checked~.menu_block {
  left: 0;
}

.menu_for_mobile span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

.menu_for_mobile span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
}

.menu_for_mobile span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 100%;
}

.menu_for_mobile>label {
  width: 6vw;
  min-width: 57px;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
}

input#on:checked~label>span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

input#on:checked~label>span:nth-child(2) {
  background: transparent;
}

input#on:checked~label>span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.content_block {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-indent: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu_for_mobile {
    display: flex;
  }
  header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!--For desktop-->
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="logo">Your Logo</div>
    <ul class="list_menu">
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Servicing</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="search_logo">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--For mobile-->
  <div class="menu_for_mobile">
    <input type="checkbox" id="on">
    <label for="on">
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                </label>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="menu_block">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Servicing</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="content_block">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad vel facilis dolorum, ratione blanditiis error, deserunt placeat officiis, voluptas sequi accusamus nihil quae! Debitis maiores nisi impedit velit odit nam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad vel facilis dolorum, ratione blanditiis error, deserunt placeat officiis, voluptas sequi accusamus nihil quae! Debitis maiores nisi impedit velit odit nam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad vel facilis dolorum, ratione blanditiis error, deserunt placeat officiis, voluptas sequi accusamus nihil quae! Debitis maiores nisi impedit velit odit nam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad vel facilis dolorum, ratione blanditiis error, deserunt placeat officiis, voluptas sequi accusamus nihil quae! Debitis maiores nisi impedit velit odit nam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad vel facilis dolorum, ratione blanditiis error, deserunt placeat officiis, voluptas sequi accusamus nihil quae! Debitis maiores nisi impedit velit odit nam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad vel facilis dolorum, ratione blanditiis error, deserunt placeat officiis, voluptas sequi accusamus nihil quae! Debitis maiores nisi impedit velit odit nam.</p>
</div>
```

upd. Еще кое-что подправил, посмотрите по коду css